# I get "undefined" when I use return;

Tags: javascript, firebase

I get a snapshot value that if I console.log it works but I when I return the value I get "undefined".

I tried changing variable and changing the return values and using **await and async**.

```js
async function GetElements(element, place) {
firebase.database().ref().child(place).orderByChild("uid").equalTo(element).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      Holder = childSnapshot.val();
    });
  }, (errorObject) => {
    console.log("User does not exist");
    document.cookie = "uid=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
    window.location.replace("login.html");
  });
  return Holder;
}
async function Test() {
  var bob = await GetElements("POkHi19eyZTfdeYECVpZByeVv2R2", "users/");
  console.log(bob)
}
Test()
```

Comment: Learn about asynchronous programming

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on. This is **especially important** when doing async code.

Comment: You'll need to promisify that `once` call if you can't `await` it.

Comment: @tadman It does return a promise. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#once

Comment: Note that there is also a `get()` function that's easier to work with (and returns a promise) if you just want a single result: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#get

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
async function GetElements(element,place) {
  firebase.database().ref().child(place).orderByChild("uid").equalTo(element).once('value', (snapshot) => {

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            
      Holder = childSnapshot.val();
      
    });

    return Holder;
  }, (errorObject) => {
    console.log("User does not exist");
    document.cookie = "uid=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
    window.location.replace("login.html");
  });
}
```

This way, the return statement will only be executed after the callback function has been called and "Holder" has been set to the correct value.